# How to Remove Request Focus from EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to remove the blue line from edittext when i touched edittext it appear but i dont know how to remove it. see the picture for more understanding[image]

Comment: show your code... and first try this you just need to asign focus to other control...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

do it this way

```
lUserNameEditText.clearFocus();
```

another way which works for me regarding the border is

```
lUserNameEditText.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the `Layout XML` like this

```
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:hint="Password" 
android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

or do it via code

```
editTextView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove requestFocus  tag in xml layout so automatically focus will loss